# onDblclick of a directive: toggle its boolean attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have a directive called `contentEditable` which is also referencing the `html5 attr` [::docs::](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/).

```
<p  contentEditable="{{edit}}" ng-model="pages.title">default</p>
```

on dblclick of directive, I would like the contentEditable's value to toggle to `true`; on blur toggle to `false`..

I've been experimenting however, the doubleclick refuses to work properly.
Not to sure on how to make this behave the way I want it.

### **[check out the JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cAHz7/180/)**

```
var app = angular.module('morningharwoodApp');
app.directive('contenteditable', function() {
  return {
  require: 'ngModel',
  scope:  {
    edit: '@'
  },
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.edit = false;
    console.log($scope.edit);
  },
  link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
    // view -> model
    elm.bind('blur', function() {
        scope.$digest(function() {
            ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());
        });
    });

    // model -> view
    ctrl.render = function(value) {
        elm.html(value);
    };

    // load init value from DOM
    ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());



    elm.bind('dblclick', function(event) {
        scope.edit = !scope.edit;
        console.log(scope.edit);


       console.log('keydown ' + event.which);
       var esc = event.which === 27,
           enter = event.which === 13,
           el = event.target;

       if (esc || enter) {
               // console.log('esc');
               ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());
               scope.editable = false;
               el.blur();
               event.preventDefault();                        
       }

      });

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Although considerably messy, the code seems to work fine on Chrome. What's the problem ?

Comment: the double click does work but it goes directly to editable after single click.  it is weird .. contentEditable in html5 has a onclick event ... I dunno if this is even possible :c

Comment: so you want to turn on edit mode only on double click yes ?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood: LOL of course. `contenteditable` is an HTML5 attribute. You should use a different name for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the scope binding incorrectly, the isolated scope binding is for binding the values between a directive's scope and a parent controller's scope, not the attribute itself.

The result of your original code is the tag will always exist and have no value like this:

```
<div contenteditable ng-model="fName"> ..
```

that why the element is always editable.

If you want to change the value of the attribute, you can use `attrs.$set()` instead. And after enabling the `contenteditable`, you have to focus the element manually, otherwise an another click is required to enter the edit mode.

```
elm.bind('dblclick', function () {
  if (!attrs.contenteditable) {
    attrs.$set('contenteditable', true);
    elm[0].focus();
  }
});
```

then reset the attribute back on blur:

```
elm.bind('blur', function () {
  attrs.$set('contenteditable', false);

  scope.$apply(function () {
    ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());
  });
});
```

also your `ENTER/ESC` key logic should be in the `keyup` event

```
elm.bind('keyup', function (event) {
  var esc = event.which === 27,
    enter = event.which === 13;

  if (esc || enter) {
    event.preventDefault();
    elm[0].blur();
  }
});
```

Please see the edited jsfiddle below for the full working example.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hMrTA/1/

Comment: Hey I've accepted the answer is there anyway to uses $digest vs $apply??  I just learned the difference and I'm curious on how to optimize for that. Otherwise, excellent answer!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) The `$apply` can accept a function/expression that would be evaluated against the scope, then it will call the `$rootScope.$digest()` afterward. So, if there is no need to pass any code into `$apply()`, running `$scope.$digest()` would be a bit faster than `$scope.$apply()`, since the former will trigger only watchers on the current $scope and its children but the later will trigger watchers on the entire $scope chain ($rootScope). However, almost of the time, the different shouldn't be that much significant, but in some rare performance bottleneck, it should helps.

Comment: nm.. .it does update it jsut doesnt update a different scope i've mapped it to.. lol nm

Comment: Forgot to mention that the `$scope.$digest()` will not work if use in a directive with an isolated scope because it will not trigger watchers of a parent scope that it is binded to. There may be some other situation like this, so you should be careful if you want to do a micro-optimization by using `$scope.$digest()`.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you get to edit the input even with single clicks is because you use the focus meta-selector to highlight it. You can achive focus state with single clicks (which also include double clicks) and hitting Tab on your keyboard until it gets selected, which I believe is more than you want.

I'd suggest rethinking your directive. One idea would be to have 2 fields: one label (showing the current value) and one input field (allowing edit) and show only one, based on the flag you're using. Bind the dblclick event on the label to change the flag (and show the input) and bind the blur event on the input to switch it back.